# I have a meteor a randomly falling meteor an I want to make more of them

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I have a meteor and when there is only one meteor the collision works, but when I add more meteors the collision stops working, which prevents health form from getting subtracted.

I tried to search on the internet, but I did not get any good answers. I also asked on some forms and they said I have to create a place to store all the meteors and then check if there are any collisions.

```js
let x = 200;
let x1 = 258;
let score = 0;
let health = 5;
let meteors = [];
let ecllipseMeteors = [];
let meteor;
let ecllipseMeteor;
let spaceShipimg;
let meteorimg;
let levels = 5;


function Meteor() {
  this.x = random(0,600);
  this.y = random(-200,-190);
  this.speed = random(3,10);

  this.fall = function() {
    this.y = this.y + this.speed;
    if (this.y > height) {
      this.y = random(-200,-100);
      this.speed = random(3, 7);
    }
  };
  this.show = function() { image(meteorimg,this.x,this.y, 40, 40) };
}
function meteormodel() {
  this.x = random(0,600);
  this.y = random(-200,-190);
  this.speed = random(3,10);

  this.fall = function() {
    this.y = this.y + this.speed;
    if (this.y > height) {
      this.y = random(-200,-100);
      this.speed = random(3, 7);
    }
  };
  this.show = function() { ellipse(this.x,this.y, 20, 20) };
}

function level() {
  if (score  == 10){
    levels = 25;
  }
}
function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 400);
  timer = createP('');
  for (let i = 0; i<5; i++) {
  meteors[i] = new Meteor();
  ecllipseMeteors[i] = new meteormodel();
}
 meteor = new Meteor();
 ecllipseMeteor = new meteormodel();
 interval = setInterval(scoreCount, 500);
}

function gameOver() {
  textSize(20);
  text("GAME OVER YOUR SCORE: " + score, 200, 200);
  fill(255);
}
function preload() {
    spaceShipimg = loadImage('assets/spaceShip.png');
  meteorimg = loadImage('assets/meteor.png');

}

function scoreCount() {
score++;
}
function draw() {
  background(11, 72, 170);
  //console.log(meteor)


  hit = collideRectCircle(x1, 335, 20, 30, meteor.x, meteor.y, 40);
  if(hit == true) {
      health -= 1;

      meteor.y = height+1;

      if (health == 0) {
          gameOver();
          noLoop();
      }
  }





    if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW) && x > -46) {
      x -= 5;
    }

    if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW) && x < 508) {
      x += 5;
    }
    if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW) && x1 > 9) {
      x1 -= 5;
    }

    if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW) && x1 < 565) {
      x1 += 5;
    }
    rect(x1, 335, 20, 30)
    image(spaceShipimg,x,260,120,120)

  for (let meteor of meteors) {
  meteor.fall();
  meteor.show();
}

    textSize(20);
    text("Health: " + health, 10, 20);
    fill(255);
    textSize(20);
    text("Score: " + score, 10, 40);
    fill(255);
}
```

I am expecting collision between meteor a spaceship-like it is with only one meteor.

Comment: You need to do your hit detection for every meteor.

Comment: So in hit instead of meteor. x and meteor,y I do meteors.x and meteors.y

Comment: See the answer by Rabbid76

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking the collision against `meteor`, you've to check the collisions against the meteors int the array `meteors`, in a loop:

```js
function draw() {
    // [...]

    for (let i = 0; i<meteors.length; i++) {
        hit = collideRectCircle(x1, 335, 20, 30, meteors[i].x, meteors[i].y, 40);
        if(hit == true) {
            health -= 1;
            meteors[i].y = height+1;
            if (health == 0) {
                gameOver();
                noLoop();
            }
        }
    }

    // [...]
}
```

`meteor` is not further needed, it is substituted by the array `meteors`, so you can delete `meteor` from the entire program.

---

Further I recommend to randomize the x coordinate of a new meteor, when it is spawned:

```js
function Meteor() {
    // [...]

    this.fall = function() {
        this.y = this.y + this.speed;
        if (this.y > height) {
            this.y = random(-200,-100);

            this.x = random(0,600); // <------ random x coordinate

            this.speed = random(3, 7);
        }
    };

    // [...]
}
```

---

```js
let x = 200;
let x1 = 258;
let score = 0;
let health = 5;
let meteors = [];
let ecllipseMeteors = [];
let spaceShipimg;
let meteorimg;
let levels = 5;

function collideRectCircle(rx, ry, rw, rh, cx, cy, cr)
{
    return rx+rw > cx-cr && cx+cr > rx && ry+rh > cy-cr && cy+cr > ry;
}

function Meteor() {
    this.x = random(40,560);
    this.y = random(-200,-190);
    this.speed = random(3,10);

    this.fall = function() {
        this.y = this.y + this.speed;
        if (this.y > height) {
            this.y = random(-200,-100);
            this.x = random(40,560);
            this.speed = random(3, 7);
        }
    };
    this.show = function() { 
        fill(128, 64, 64)
        ellipse(this.x,this.y, 40, 40)
        //image(meteorimg,this.x,this.y, 40, 40)
    };
}

function meteormodel() {
    this.x = random(0,600);
    this.y = random(-200,-190);
    this.speed = random(3,10);
  
    /*
    this.fall = function() {
        this.y = this.y + this.speed;
        if (this.y > height) {
            this.y = random(-200,-100);
            //this.x = random(40,560);
            this.speed = random(3, 7);
        }
    };
    */
    this.show = function() { ellipse(this.x,this.y, 20, 20) };
}

function level() {
    if (score  == 10){
        levels = 25;
    }
}
function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 400);
    //timer = createP('');
    for (let i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        meteors[i] = new Meteor();
        ecllipseMeteors[i] = new meteormodel();
    }
   
    interval = setInterval(scoreCount, 500);
}

function gameOver() {
    textSize(20);
    text("GAME OVER YOUR SCORE: " + score, 200, 200);
    fill(255);
}

function preload() {
    //spaceShipimg = loadImage('assets/spaceShip.png');
    //meteorimg = loadImage('assets/meteor.png');
}

function scoreCount() {
    score++;
}

function draw() {
    background(11, 72, 170);
    //console.log(meteor)

    for (let i = 0; i<meteors.length; i++) {
        hit = collideRectCircle(x1, 335, 20, 30, meteors[i].x, meteors[i].y, 40);
        if(hit == true) {
            health -= 1;
            meteors[i].y = height+1;
            if (health == 0) {
                gameOver();
                noLoop();
            }
        }
    }

    if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW) && x > -46) {
        x -= 5;
    }

    if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW) && x < 508) {
        x += 5;
    }
    if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW) && x1 > 9) {
        x1 -= 5;
    }
    if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW) && x1 < 565) {
        x1 += 5;
    }
    fill(255, 255, 0)
    rect(x1, 335, 20, 30)
    //image(spaceShipimg,x,260,120,120)

    for (let meteor of meteors) {
        meteor.fall();
        meteor.show();
    }

    fill(255);
    textSize(20);
    text("Health: " + health, 10, 20);
    textSize(20);
    text("Score: " + score, 10, 40);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: the collision still does not work. The rockets are falling,  but nothing happens

Comment: @Lime What are you doing in `collideRectCircle`? Do you use there `meteor` rather than the input parameter?

Comment: In collide I use meteor

Comment: you are a very good teacher. I just placed a new question can you maybe take a look at it.